# Include Metropolis theme's standout frames in framecount

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

The Metropolis beamer theme excludes its `standout` frames from the frame count with the frame option `noframenumbering`. Is there any way to override this? Preferably without rewriting the whole `standout` template.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{First frame}  % Numbered as "1"
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}[standout]  % Also numbered as "1" but in same color as background
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Second frame}  % Numbered as "2", but would preferably be "3"
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, which essentially involve some manual tweaking of the frame numbering. The fastest way I found is to simply add `\stepcounter{framenumber}` **after** the `standout` frame or within the frame following it:

```
\begin{frame}[standout]
    Hello, world!
\end{frame}
\stepcounter{framenumber}
```

If you use a lot of the `standout`-type frames, you may want to consider defining a custom environment which includes this command.